# How to synchronize a code based on condition in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

We have the following code to execute in Java:

```
public void doSomething() {
    doSomeDBOperationForOrg();
    doOtherOperations();
}

void doSomeDBOperationForOrg() { 
    //should be executed only once per organization.
}

void doOtherOperations() {
    //should be executed only when the DB operation for the organization is done, and not before
}
```

The method `doSomething` is being called at the same time by multiple users under multiple organizations. We need to execute method `doSomeDBOperationForOrg` only once per organization, and `doOtherOperations` for all the users calling the `doSomething` method, but only after `doSomeDBOperationForOrg` is complete.

One option is to have "synchronized" over `doSomething` and/or `doSomeDBOperationForOrg`, and maintain a list of updated orgaizations.

```
public synchronized void doSomething() {
    if(!orgUpdatedList.contains(organization)) {
        doSomeDBOperationForOrg();
        orgUpdatedList.add(organization);
    }
    
    doOtherOperations();
}
```

But that will block all the threads from users irrespective of their organizations. This is not desirable, when we have a huge list of users.
Can someone please advise a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to execute `doOtherOperations();` freely in parallel, so this should not be in any (effective) `synchronized` block.

But you want `doSomeDBOperationForOrg();` to happen once per organization. As you deal with multiple threads, requirements like "once per xyz" need some sort of synchronization.

And you don't want users to wait for initialization of an organization they don't belong to.

Suggestions:

If you have a class (let's call it `Organization`) representing the organizations (in the sense that one organization is mapped 1:1 to exactly one instance, without duplicate instances for the same organization), then you can make `doSomeDBOperationForOrg();` a synchronized instance method of the `Organization` class, and have this method check whether the initialization is necessary. Then `doSomething()` is quite simple:

```
public void doSomething() {
    organization.doSomeDBOperationForOrg();
    doOtherOperations();
}
```

Or, closer to you current structure:

```
public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (organization) {
        if(!orgUpdatedList.contains(organization)) {
            doSomeDBOperationForOrg();
            orgUpdatedList.add(organization);
        }
    }
    doOtherOperations();
}
```

But make sure, you use a thread-safe `orgUpdatedList`, e.g. by wrapping `Collections.synchronizedXyz()` around it!

By synchronizing on the organization, you make sure that users from one organization can block one another, so that there's an orderly initialization, but aren't affected by users from other organizations.

If you don't have an appropriate `Organization` class (and can't introduce one), but only a `String`, you can synchronize on `organization.intern()`. That method has the property that all Strings with the same content result in the identical instance. It's kind of a hack, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global hashmap as lock for the said key, and in actual code condition check if the value already present if yes then return or wait till that hashmap value gets cleared

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).